# What is the default username and password for the KUCAM 1080P 2.0?

Tags: webcam, authentication, user-interface, default-settings

I just purchased the [KUCAM 1080P 2.0 Mega Wireless Wifi IP Security Camera, Night Vision, Plug/Play, Pan/Tilt, ONVIF with Remote Video Surveillance Monitoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011KO8RVS), and I'm wondering what the default username and password is for the web interface?

Some Amazon customers are reporting the support email to be at @kucamtech.com, but they don't have *any* kind of website hosted at the domain. It seems now they go by the name Wansview, I found this link internally in the firmware https://nwsvr1.com/ and did some searching and it seems this camera was later marketed as the [Wansview NCM-624W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K74OR5I).

The interface use HTTP Basic Authentication and the server says "IPCamera Login".

When I do an `nmap -sP` to find the camera, the MAC Address resolves to `Shenzhen Smarteye Digital Electronics`.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Evan in 2015. You're a wonderful person for asking a question EIGHT YEARS before I would have the _same_ problem. I'm glad you bought the same crappy IP camera I did on sale at the same time I bought it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults are

```
username: admin
password: 123456
```

Side note, I wrote to Wansview and asked for an update to the firmware, they wrote back and said,

> Thank you for your reply. I asked our engineers. This camera you have
> is indeed our product from many years ago. Since we don't produce and
> sell it anymore, the firmware of this camera can't be upgraded.
>
> It should be reminded that this camera has been used for a very long
> time, if you force to upgrade the firmware, there is also a risk that
> the firmware upgrade will fail and cause the camera to lock up and
> stop working. So we don't have a latest firmware as well as we don't
> recommend you to upgrade the firmware. Hope you can understand.
>
> I apologize for not being able to help you, if you have any other
> questions, please feel free to contact me.